# Compute mean of last X elements of a list in Python2.7

Tags: python, numpy, mean

Is there an elegant way or function to compute the mean of the last X elements of a list?

I have a list `register` that increases in size at each iterations :

```
register = np.append(register, value)
```

I want to create another list in which an `i` element corresponds to the mean of the `X` last elements in `register`

```
register_mean[i] = np.mean(register[i-X:i])
```

The tricky part is for the first `X` iterations, when there isn't `X` values yet in `register`. For these specific cases, I would like it to compute the mean on the firsts values of `register`, and only take the first value of `register` as first value of `register_mean`.

This could be done during the iterations or after, when `register` is complete.

> I know there is lots of similar questions but haven't found one that answered this particular problem

Comment: Can you give us a sample snippet that we can run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be something as simple as

```
if X < i:
 register_mean[i] = np.mean(register[:i])
```

This just averages however many prior points there are until you have enough to average X points

Perhaps I misinterpreted your intent!

Comment: Actually, if you are just appending to the list, you don't even need the [:i]. The list will be of length i

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the work:

```
X = 4 # Span of mean
register_mean = [np.mean(register[max(i-X, 0): max(i-X, 0) + 1]) for i in range(len(register))]
```

It will essentially create a moving average of the `register` elements between `i - X` and `i`; however, whenever `i - X` is negative, it will only take the values between `0` and  `i + 1`.

Comment: Shouldn't the upper limit for the range that specifies values to pick from `register` be `max(i, 0) + 1`?